# ASP.NET MVC View HTML collapse expand

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3, formatting

I work a lot with collapsing or expanding feature of Visual Studio when working on ASPX or HTML files. However, in ASP.NET MVC View, there is no such a feature and things really get messy and unmanageable as your view become more and more complicated.

Does anyone know how can I enable HTML collapse/expand in ASP.NET MVC View?

[image]

Comment: you may want to add an exemple or an image or what you are considering "messy and unmanageable". I assumed in my answer that it is the visual aspect ("HTML collapse/expand"), but you would avoid confusion with an exemple :)

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio, you can manually add outlined region like this :

> To create or remove a collapsible region
>
> 1. Select the text you want to treat as a collapsible region.
> 2. To create a collapsible region, on the Edit menu, point to Outlining, and then click Hide Selection.
>
> The editor turns the selection into a region, collapses it, and
>   displays a box with an ellipsis (...) to indicate that the area
>   contains a collapsed area. You can hold the mouse pointer over the box
>   to see its contents.
>
> 3. To remove a collapsible region, collapse it, and then click it to select it.
> 4. On the Edit menu, point to Outlining, and then click Stop Hiding Current.
>
> To collapse and expand a single region
>
> 1. To collapse a region, click the minus sign (-) in the margin of the editor.
> 2. To expand a collapsed region, click the plus sign (+) in the margin.
>
> To collapse and expand all regions
>
> On the Edit menu, point to Outlining, and then click Toggle All
>   Outlining.

[From MSDN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeoTy.png)

But that's not really practical.

For HTML you can manually edit the outline option for each tags  in the text editors options :

[image]

[image]

Minimum value of minimum lines is 1 to be effective.

[More info on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178724.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Partial Views](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/re-use-ui-using-master-pages-and-partials) to keep your markup clean.

Update: 
But if you want to simply collapse various parts of your view, you can select some text, right click it and select Collapse Tag.

Comment: And I think ReSharper might add expand/collapse support in razor views.

Comment: Your answer is not related at all, though your comment is relevant. Changed them buddy. :)

Comment: I disagree. The core problem of "messy" views is improper use of views.

Comment: Why do you falsify buddy. Sometimes even in small views, you need to get a chunk of your code, and copy/paste it somewhere else. You need to collapse the HTML container.

Answer (score 1):

(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) and (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) seem to be working for me.